# Cannot read property style of null issue

Tags: javascript, properties, null

I've made this function that gives the error

> Cannot read property 'style' of null

Can you please help me figure out what the problem is?

```
function cade()
{
    var a = document.getElementById(this.id).style.top;
    a = a + 100;
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.top =  a+'px';
}
cade.call(document.getElementById("p"));
```

Comment: document.getElementById(this.id) is returning null

Comment: I have the div with the 'p' id. Why could this be invalid?

Comment: Inside the function what does `console.log(this)` return? If it's `null` (as it seems likely to be) you probably need to read this question and its accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/82548

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML and any CSS that may apply to it? I suspect this is related to missing style rules causing the `top` not to be applied, rather than problems with the ID or execution order.

Answer (score 0):

While your function works correctly, the styling on that element prevents you from doing much to move it. Adding `position: absolute` or something along those lines will make it move correctly.

Since you're passing the element as `this`, you don't need to fetch it again using `getElementById`. The reference you have is already perfectly valid, so you can simplify the code like:

```js
function cade() {
  var a = this.style.top;
  a = a + 100;
  this.style.top = a + 'px';
}
cade.call(document.getElementById("p"));
```

```css
div#p {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">This is some text.</div>
```